# Raspberry pi refuse to update

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed my Raspberry Pi with the Raspberry OS 32-bit. I have a internet Connection but i dont get the correct time and more important i dont can make updates.
I tried it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

but nothing fixed my problem.

Here is the error Message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.135.141 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease  503  Service 
Unavailable [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  503  Service 
Unavailable [IP: 93.93.135.141 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Time and updates are entirely unrelated. As you can see from the output, the update server is simply not working at the moment.

Comment: What means, i should wait and try again later.

Comment: "_i should wait and try again later_" - correct... 503 is a server-side error. This server appears to be working for me, can you try again?

Comment: When was the last time your device installed an update.  If you don’t know check the logs

Comment: "This server appears to be working for me, can you try again?" still the same error. 

"When was the last time your device installed an update" never its a fresh installed OS

Comment: @DanielB not sure what you mean by "time and updates are entirely unrelated". apt update with wrong date results in "Certificate verification failed" on my RPI.

Comment: I mean this specific case. Where the error he’s getting is not related to the time.

Comment: i have the wrong date and time, is it possible that the server refuse me to connect to them?

Comment: @Coolar - Yes; it is